# Negative number returns by abs method

Tags: java

I dont understand why the abs method would return a non-negative number when I input a negative number as parameter to the abs method.

Like abs(-5), why it returns 5 instead of -5? Its less than 0.

```
public static int abs(int a) {
if (a < 0) {
 return -a;
} else {
 return a;
}
}
```

Comment: try 'return -1 * a' instead

Comment: Why _would_ you expect a negative output? It seems that you misunderstand what `abs` does.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
if (-5 < 0) {
    return -(-5)
}
```

This will return 5.

Comment: ohhh, I see! Thanks!